# pagination results different ways in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen two ways of paginations I would like to know the differences between them. Or if there is a strict way to use either of them. Please don't mind the type of data used in the example.

First one

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'query_value' => 'string',
        'status'      => ['string', Rule::in(BaseModel::STATUS_CODES)],
        'pagination'  => 'integer',
    ];
}

public function paginationResult()
{
    return !is_null($this->get('pagination')) && $this->get('pagination') > 0 ? $this->get('pagination') : 10;
}
```

in a controller

```
$this->itemsPerPage = $filterRequest->paginationResult();
```

Second one

```
$users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: only one of those gets a paginator

Comment: Can you elaborate on the situation to use one of them. I'm just curious about the core differences.

Comment: The first one only returns the value of the pagination attribute from the request. So, in short it will return an integer. The second one will however return a paginator instance and thus when you return it you will get pagination.

Comment: yes it will return an int then be used in other function `protected function paginate($query)
    {
        if ($this->itemsPerPage == -1) {
            $this->itemsPerPage = $query->count();
            $this->page = 1;
        }
        return $query->paginate((int) $this->itemsPerPage, ['*'], 'page', (int) $this->page);
    }` but why the first one is a long way to get pagniation ?

Answer (score 0):

FormRequest class

```php
class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'query_value' => 'string',
            'status'      => ['string', Rule::in(BaseModel::STATUS_CODES)],
            'pagination'  => 'integer',
        ];
    }

    public function paginationValue()
    {
        return $this->pagination ?: 10;
    }
}
```

Then in controller

```php
public function index(UserRequest $request)
{
    $users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->paginate($request->paginationValue());

    //...rest of method code
}
```

The `paginate()` method will return an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` which means that you can display links like `1` `2` ......`9` `10` - numbers show the page numbers for paginated results

Another way to paginate is using `simplePaginate()` which will return an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`, which means you can display links as `Prev` `Next`